# MS-Sql Selecting from Horizontally Partitioned Tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a horizontally partitioned table system, using check-constraints on a Date_Key reference where the Date is actually the YYYYMMDD integer version of the date (so check-constraints are between YYYY0101 and YYYY1231).

I have a View that uses UNION ALL for all tables.

If I execute

```
Select * from MyDatedTable DT 
inner join MyDates M on DT.Date_Key = MD.Date_Key and MD.Date_Key = 20120115
```

the optimizer "knows" to only scan and read the correct 2012 table (or index), and ignores all other tables that are unioned.

HOWEVER

if I use a `lookup-value` in the `MyDates` table (for example `Year`) it DOES NOT use the `check-constraint` on the `Key-relationship`, 
ie:

```
Select * from MyDatedTable DT 
inner join MyDates MD on DT.Date_Key = MD.Date_Key and MD.Year = 2012 and MD.Month = 1 and MD.Day = 15
```

(The optimizer "knows" that zero rows will come from the tables that are outside the range, but it does show that it needs to actually check the index...)

Is there a way to get MS-SQL (2012) to optimize this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the existence of the following objects (two tables and one view):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyDates2013 (
    Date_Key INT PRIMARY KEY,
        CHECK (Date_Key BETWEEN 20130101 AND 20131231),
    [Year] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [Month] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [Day] TINYINT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyDates2013 (Date_Key, [Year], [Month], [Day])
VALUES (20130101, 2013, 1, 1);

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyDates2014 (
    Date_Key INT PRIMARY KEY,
        CHECK (Date_Key BETWEEN 20140101 AND 20141231),
    [Year] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [Month] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [Day] TINYINT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyDates2014 (Date_Key, [Year], [Month], [Day])
VALUES (20140101, 2014, 1, 1);

GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.My Dates
AS
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyDates2013
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyDates2014;
GO
```

the following query

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.MyDates MD
WHERE   MD.Date_Key = 20140115;
```

is (indeed) optimized by SQL Server, the execution plan

[image]

including only one `Index Seek` (on    primary key of `dbo.MyDates2014`) because at compile time SQL Server *knows* that `Date_Key = 20140115` can be within only one base table: `dbo.MyDates2014`. This is possible because of a `CHECK` constraint defined on `dbo.MyDates2014`: `CHECK (Date_Key BETWEEN 20140101 AND 20141231)`.

The next query

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.MyDates MD
WHERE   MD.[Year] = 2014 AND MD.[Month] = 1 AND MD.[Day] = 15;
GO
```

is different

[image]

because:

{1} There is no indexes on `Year`, `Month` and `Day` columns within every table (and this it causes those `Clustered Index Scan`s) but also because

{2} SQL Server will read both tables used by `dbo.MyDates` view. This happens because it doesn't know the correlation between `Date_Key` values and `[Year], [Month], [Day]` values and (I suppose) it can't infer from a constraint like this `CHECK (Date_Key BETWEEN 20140101 AND 20141231)` and new rule/constraint `[Year] = 2014`.

**Solution #1:**

So, one solution is to add these constraints within every table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyDates2013 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MyDates2013_Year CHECK ( [Year] = 2013 );
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyDates2014 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MyDates2014_Year CHECK ( [Year] = 2014 );
GO
```

Now, the execution plan includes only one `Scan`: `Clustered Index Scan` on `dbo.MyDates2014`:

[image]

This way will solved only problem #2. For #1 you need indexes.

**Solution #2:**

Another solution is to simply translate `MD.[Year] = 2014 AND MD.[Month] = 1 AND MD.[Day] = 15` predicates into `MD.Date_Key = 20140115`. Following example will use `RECOMPILE` query hint to force SQL Server to generate a execution plan optimized for every execution (for current values of parameters):

```
DECLARE @Year SMALLINT, @Month TINYINT, @Day TINYINT;
SELECT  @Year = 2014, @Month = 1, @Day = 15;
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.MyDates MD
WHERE   MD.Date_Key = (@Year * 100 + @Month) * 100 + @Day
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
GO
```

[image]

Thus SQL Server will remove unnecessary `Index Seek`s / `Index Scan`s operators (for example `Index Seek` on `dbo.MyTable2013` when `@Year` = `2014`).

Even without OPTION(RECOMPILE)

```
DECLARE @Year SMALLINT, @Month TINYINT, @Day TINYINT;
SELECT  @Year = 2014, @Month = 1, @Day = 15;
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.MyDates MD
WHERE   MD.Date_Key = (@Year * 100 + @Month) * 100 + @Day
```

you could get a good performance because execution plan includes `Filter` operators which prevent unnecessary reads (`Index Seek`/`Scan`):

[image]

Note #1: You should test yourself these solutions before choosing one of them (if).

Note #2: I have to say that I used SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thank you. I found this wasn't actually as much of an issue as I thought. After careful analysis I found that although the optimizer does list each of the BaseTable indexes for a possible seek/scan, it also pre-sets this with the filter. So looking at a full profile it never even opens and uses those indexes after all, it just displays that it "might". Luckily enough, even when I extend my Parent/Forign Keys to joins that go outside of every column in my main (or other) indexes it also does the same to gather the primary rows fist. Thanks